# Generate a clean JSON from a wrapper class for REST API

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community, salesforcedx

I am trying to create a JSON for outside REST API..
My code looks like -->

```
public class FordAccountAPI{
    public static void SendAccountInfo(list<id> fordaccId) {
        List<FORDAccountAPIWrapper> SendFordAccountAPI = new List<FORDAccountAPIWrapper>();
        
        list<account> acc = [Select Id,Building_Experience__c,Favourite_Feature__c,Non_negotiable_items__c,Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink__c,Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink__c,Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink__c,Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink__c,Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink__c,Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink__c,Primary_Client_s_Diet_Preference__c,Secondary_Client_s_Diet_Preference__c,Primary_Client_s_Design_Taste__c,Secondary_Client_s_Design_Taste__c,Main_Contact__c,Communication_Frequency__c,Preferred_Communication_Time__c,Preferred_Communication_Mode__c,No_Communication__c,(select Id,Details__c from Family__r),(select Id,Details__c from Occupation__r),(select Id,Details__c from Recreation__r),(select Id,Details__c from Dream__r),(select Id,Details__c from Support_Journey__r),(select Id,Date__c,Details__c from Important_Dates__r),(select Id,Interior_Designer_Notes__c,SC_Design_Ideas__c from WOS_Ideas__r) from Account where id in : fordaccId];
                
        for (Account tempAcc : acc){
            FORDAccountAPIWrapper wrapperinner = new FORDAccountAPIWrapper();
            
            wrapperinner.AccountId  = tempAcc.Id;
            wrapperinner.Building_Experience = (tempAcc.Building_Experience__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Building_Experience__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Favourite_Feature = (tempAcc.Favourite_Feature__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Favourite_Feature__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Non_negotiable_items = (tempAcc.Non_negotiable_items__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Non_negotiable_items__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink = (tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink = (tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink = (tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink = (tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink = (tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink = (tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Primary_Client_s_Diet_Preference = (tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Diet_Preference__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Diet_Preference__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Secondary_Client_s_Diet_Preference = (tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Diet_Preference__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Diet_Preference__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Primary_Client_s_Design_Taste = (tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Design_Taste__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Primary_Client_s_Design_Taste__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Secondary_Client_s_Design_Taste = (tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Design_Taste__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Secondary_Client_s_Design_Taste__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Main_Contact = (tempAcc.Main_Contact__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Main_Contact__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Communication_Frequency = (tempAcc.Communication_Frequency__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Communication_Frequency__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Preferred_Communication_Time = (tempAcc.Preferred_Communication_Time__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Preferred_Communication_Time__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.Preferred_Communication_Mode = (tempAcc.Preferred_Communication_Mode__c  != null) ? tempAcc.Preferred_Communication_Mode__c  : '';
            wrapperinner.No_Communication = (tempAcc.No_Communication__c  != null) ? tempAcc.No_Communication__c  : '';
            
            for(Family__c fm : tempAcc.Family__r){
                Family__c fp = new Family__c();
                fp.Id = (fm.Id != null ? fm.Id : '');   
                fp.Details__c = (fm.Details__c != null ? fm.Details__c : '');
                wrapperinner.Family.add(fp);
            }
            
            for(Occupation__c oc : tempAcc.Occupation__r){
                Occupation__c op = new Occupation__c();
                op.Id = (oc.Id != null ? oc.Id : '');   
                op.Details__c = (oc.Details__c != null ? oc.Details__c : '');
                wrapperinner.Occupation.add(op);
            }
            
            for(Recreation__c rc : tempAcc.Recreation__r){
                Recreation__c rp = new Recreation__c();
                rp.Id = (rc.Id != null ? rc.Id : '');   
                rp.Details__c = (rc.Details__c != null ? rc.Details__c : '');
                wrapperinner.Recreation.add(rp);
            }
            
            for(Dream__c dr : tempAcc.Dream__r){
                Dream__c dp = new Dream__c();
                dp.Id = (dr.Id != null ? dr.Id : '');   
                dp.Details__c = (dr.Details__c != null ? dr.Details__c : '');
                wrapperinner.Dream.add(dp);
            }
            
            for(Support_Journey__c sj : tempAcc.Support_Journey__r){
                Support_Journey__c sp = new Support_Journey__c();
                sp.Id = (sj.Id != null ? sj.Id : '');   
                sp.Details__c = (sj.Details__c != null ? sj.Details__c : '');
                wrapperinner.SupportJourney.add(sp);
            }
            
            for(Important_Date__c im : tempAcc.Important_Dates__r){
                Important_Date__c ip = new Important_Date__c();
                ip.Id = (im.Id != null ? im.Id : '');
                ip.Date__c = im.Date__c;        
                ip.Details__c = (im.Details__c != null ? im.Details__c : '');
                wrapperinner.ImportantDate.add(ip);
            }
            
            for(WOS_Idea__c wi : tempAcc.WOS_Ideas__r){
                WOS_Idea__c wp = new WOS_Idea__c();
                wp.Id = (wi.Id != null ? wi.Id : '');
                wp.Interior_Designer_Notes__c = (wi.Interior_Designer_Notes__c != null ? wi.Interior_Designer_Notes__c : '');
                wp.SC_Design_Ideas__c = (wi.SC_Design_Ideas__c != null ? wi.SC_Design_Ideas__c : '');
                wrapperinner.WOSIdeas.add(wp);
            }
            
            SendFordAccountAPI.add(wrapperinner);
        }
        
        system.debug('list of account change is'+SendFordAccountAPI);
        system.debug('checking the log injson>>>>'+JSON.serialize(SendFordAccountAPI));
        String jsonString = JSON.serialize(SendFordAccountAPI);
        system.debug('JSON@@: '+jsonString);
        If(!SendFordAccountAPI.isempty() && !Test.isRunningTest()) 
        {
            FordAccountChangeAPI(jsonString);
            //system.debug('I am sending@@');
        }
        
    }
    
    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void FordAccountChangeAPI(string JSONData) 
    {
        EndPoint_Utility.EndPointWrapper SendAccountInfoEndPoint = new EndPoint_Utility.EndPointWrapper();
        SendAccountInfoEndPoint = EndPoint_Utility.SendAccountInfo();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-type','Application/json');
        req.setHeader('Client_id',SendAccountInfoEndPoint.Client_id);
        req.setHeader('Client_secret',SendAccountInfoEndPoint.Client_secret);
        req.setEndpoint(SendAccountInfoEndPoint.EndPoint);
        
        req.setBody(JSONData); 
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        Map<String, Object> authresponse = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        string message = String.valueOf(authresponse.get('RETURN'));
        //system.debug('message@@'+message);
    }
    
    public class FORDAccountAPIWrapper{
        public String AccountId;
        public String Building_Experience;
        public String Favourite_Feature;
        public String Non_negotiable_items;
        public String Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink;
        public String Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink;
        public String Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink;
        public String Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink;
        public String Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink;
        public String Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink;
        public String Primary_Client_s_Diet_Preference;
        public String Secondary_Client_s_Diet_Preference;
        public String Primary_Client_s_Design_Taste;
        public String Secondary_Client_s_Design_Taste;
        public String Main_Contact;
        public String Communication_Frequency;
        public String Preferred_Communication_Time;
        public String Preferred_Communication_Mode;
        public String No_Communication;
        public List<Family__c> Family;
        public List<Occupation__c> Occupation;
        public List<Recreation__c> Recreation;
        public List<Dream__c> Dream;
        public List<Support_Journey__c> SupportJourney;
        public List<Important_Date__c> ImportantDate;
        public List<WOS_Idea__c> WOSIdeas;
        
        public FORDAccountAPIWrapper(){
            AccountId = '';
            Building_Experience = '';
            Favourite_Feature = '';
            Non_negotiable_items = '';
            Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink = '';
            Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Hot_Drink = '';
            Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink = '';
            Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Cold_Drink = '';
            Primary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink = '';
            Secondary_Client_s_Preferred_Drink = '';
            Primary_Client_s_Diet_Preference = '';
            Secondary_Client_s_Diet_Preference = '';
            Primary_Client_s_Design_Taste = '';
            Secondary_Client_s_Design_Taste = '';
            Main_Contact = '';
            Communication_Frequency = '';
            Preferred_Communication_Time = '';
            Preferred_Communication_Mode = '';
            No_Communication = '';
            Family = new List<Family__c>();
            Occupation = new List<Occupation__c>();
            Recreation = new List<Recreation__c>();
            Dream = new List<Dream__c>();
            SupportJourney = new List<Support_Journey__c>();
            ImportantDate = new List<Important_Date__c>();
            WOSIdeas = new List<WOS_Idea__c>();
          }
        
    }
}
```

Its working fine but generated JSON is not clean. When I am checking the debug of JSON.serialize(SendFordAccountAPI) it looks like having lots of unwanted parameters -->

```
[
   {
      "WOSIdeas":[
         {
            "attributes":{
               "type":"WOS_Idea__c",
               "url":"/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/WOS_Idea__c/a1Q0w000000RGdBEAW"
            },
            "Id":"a1Q0w000000RGdBEAW",
            "Interior_Designer_Notes__c":"He has selected all grange range doors for his new build.",
            "SC_Design_Ideas__c":"He is happy with grange and want grange range toilet fittings."
         },
         {
            "attributes":{
               "type":"WOS_Idea__c",
               "url":"/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/WOS_Idea__c/a1Q0w000000RGd1EAG"
            },
            "Id":"a1Q0w000000RGd1EAG",
            "Interior_Designer_Notes__c":"He has selected all grange range doors for his new build.",
            "SC_Design_Ideas__c":"He is happy with grange and want grange range toilet fittings."
         }
      ],
      "SupportJourney":[
         {
            "attributes":{
               "type":"Support_Journey__c",
               "url":"/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Support_Journey__c/a1P0w000000CjOsEAK"
            },
            "Id":"a1P0w000000CjOsEAK",
            "Details__c":"He is worried with all the build steps."
         }
   }
]
```

I just want to have a clean JSON to sent to other system and should look like this --> (basically remove unwanted 'attribute' paramter and sub parameter 'type', 'url' from it)

```
[
   {
      "WOSIdeas":[
         {
            "Id":"a1Q0w000000RGdBEAW",
            "Interior_Designer_Notes__c":"He has selected all grange range doors for his new build.",
            "SC_Design_Ideas__c":"He is happy with grange and want grange range toilet fittings."
         },
         {
            "Id":"a1Q0w000000RGd1EAG",
            "Interior_Designer_Notes__c":"He has selected all grange range doors for his new build.",
            "SC_Design_Ideas__c":"He is happy with grange and want grange range toilet fittings."
         }
      ],
      "SupportJourney":[
         {
            "Id":"a1P0w000000CjOsEAK",
            "Details__c":"He is worried with all the build steps."
         }
   }
]
```

I have tried a couple of solutions from web but nothing is working.

Comment: Stop using SObjects in your wrapper and switch to using `Map<String, Object>` for these instead, set from the SObject's populated fields map.

Comment: In the wrapper class I switched public List<Family__c> Family --> public Map<String, Family__c> Family; This resulted in JSON --> 
[
   {
      "WOSIdeas":{
         "a1Q0w000000RGcmEAG":{    //Key of the map is adding to the JSON
            "attributes":{
               "type":"WOS_Idea__c",
               "url":""
            },
            "Id":"a1Q0w000000RGcmEAG",
            "Interior_Designer_Notes__c":"",
            "SC_Design_Ideas__c":""
         }
      }
   }
]
Addition of the Key of the Map. which is not what we want.

Comment: You have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this "dirty" JSON, you need to stop using SObjects in your wrapper class entirely.

An SObject can provide you access to a Map, using [SObject.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm). If you *replace* your SObjects in the wrapper with `Map<String, Object>` and populate these maps with the result of calling get populated fields as map you should get the output you want.

For example, change `Family` from (what I assume is) `List<SObject>` to be `List<Map<String, Object>>` instead then update:

```
for (Family__c fm : tempAcc.Family__r){
    Family__c fp = new Family__c();
    fp.Id = (fm.Id != null ? fm.Id : '');   
    fp.Details__c = (fm.Details__c != null ? fm.Details__c : '');
    wrapperinner.Family.add(fp);
}
```

to:

```
for (Family__c fm : tempAcc.Family__r) {
    Family__c fp = new Family__c();
    fp.Id = (fm.Id != null ? fm.Id : '');   
    fp.Details__c = (fm.Details__c != null ? fm.Details__c : '');
    wrapperinner.Family.add(fp.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap());
}
```

Change all other cases in a similar way. NB: I have assumed that you don't have populated fields here that are themselves SObject records.

Comment: You are legend @Pil W. That was perfect. Thanks a lot.